# Fourier series solution of the heat equation on $-2<x<2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

I have to solve the following boundary value problem:
$u_t=u_{xx}$, $u(t,-2)=u(t,2)=0$ and $u(0,x)=f(x)$.
I tried to solve the problem using the method of separation of variables. So assume $u(t,x)=v(t)w(x)$. Then the PDE reduces to the two following ODE's:
$$v'(t)=\lambda v(t)\text{ and } w''(x)=\lambda w(x)$$ 
for some constant $\lambda$ to be determined by the boundary values. So for the first one we see that $v(t)=e^{\lambda t}$ is a solution and for the second we have three cases. I only want to look at the case that $\lambda=-\omega^2<0$. Then we have solutions $\cos(\omega x)$ and $\sin(\omega x)$. Now lets look at the boundary conditions. So we have that $u(t,x)=e^{\lambda t}(a\sin(\omega x)+b\cos(\omega x))$. Then $0=e^{-\lambda t}u(t,-2)=a\sin(-2\omega )+b\cos(2\omega)=e^{-\lambda t}u(t,2)=a\sin(2\omega )+b\cos(2\omega)$. So if $\omega_n=n\pi/2$ then we must have that $b=0$. If $\omega_n=n\pi/2+\pi/4$ then we must have that $a=0$. Then I would say that the general solution becomes
$$u(t,x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_ne^{-t(n\pi/2)^2}\sin(n\pi x/2)+b_ne^{-t(n\pi/2+\pi/4)^2}\cos(x(n\pi/2+\pi/4))$$.

My problem now is that I have no clue how to find the coefficients, since this doesnt look like a normal fouerier series, because the arguments of the sine and cosine are different. Thanks in advance for looking at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier approach would be to start with the change of variable $y=x+2$ so that you can deal with the problem on $[0,4]$. Then $\sin \left ( \frac{n \pi y}{4} \right )$ will be the appropriate eigenfunctions for homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. The nice thing about this approach is that $\sin(\omega \cdot 0)=0$ and $\cos(\omega \cdot 0)=1$ regardless of what $\omega$ is. This makes dealing with the boundary conditions easier.

With your approach, you essentially have to represent $\sin \left ( \frac{n \pi (x+2)}{4} \right )$ as a sum of a sine and a cosine. This can always be done, but it doesn't seem necessary to me.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Ok, I see that this makes life easier :D. But can we find the coefficients using the method I proposed above? How would one do it?

Comment: @Badshah I think you would just need to do the integrations. I was playing with Wolfram, with inputs like http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%282*pi*%28x%2B2%29%2F4%29 and it looks like you were actually correct, and $\sin \left ( \frac{n \pi (x+2)}{4} \right )$ can be written as just a sine or a cosine with no phase shift for each $n$. This actually makes sense because $\sin \left ( \frac{n \pi (x+2)}{4} \right )=\sin \left ( \frac{n \pi x}{4} + \frac{n \pi}{2} \right )$. This can be reduced by using the even-odd and cofunction identities repeatedly.

Comment: @Badshah For example, $\sin(\pi (x+2)/4) = \sin(\pi x/4 + \pi/2) = \sin(\pi/2 - (-\pi x/4))=\cos(-\pi x/4)=\cos(\pi x/4)$.